# logstash converting ruby code to logstash filters

Tags: logstash

I was wondering what will be the best way to implement the following task in logstash :

I have the following field that contains multiple paths divided by ':' :

```
my_field : "/var/log/my_custom_file.txt:/var/log/otherfile.log/:/root/aaa.jar
```

I want to add a new field called "first_file" that will contain only the file_name(without suffix) of the first path :

```
first_file : my_custom_file
```

I implemented it with the following ruby code ;

```
  code => 'event.set("first_file",event.get("[my_field]").split(":")[0].split("/")[-1].split(".")[0])'
```

How can I use logstash filters (add_field,split,grok) to do the same task ? I feel like using ruby code should be my last option.

Comment: the number of ":" separator is always the same?

Comment: no its not always the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using just grok, but I think it would be clearer to use mutate to pull out the first value

```
mutate { split => { "my_field" => ":" } }
mutate { replace => "{ "my_field" => "[my_field][0]" } }
grok { match => { "my_field" => "/(?<my_field>[^/]+)\.%{WORD}$" } overwrite => [ "my_field" ] }
```

rather than

```
grok { match => { "my_field" => "/(?<my_field>[^/]+)\.%{WORD}:" } overwrite => [ "my_field" ] }
```

The (?<my_field>[^/]+) is a custom pattern (documented [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_custom_patterns)) which creates a field called [my_field] from a sequence of one or more (+) characters which are not /

Comment: Can you please explain the regex /(?<my_field>[^/]+)\ in the grok ?

Comment: I updated the answer to briefly explain custom patterns.

Comment: Thank you for the gr8 answer and the clear explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes with a basic grok you could match every field in the value.

This kind of filter must work (put it in your logstash configuration file), this one extract the "basename" of the file (filename without extension and path) :

```
filter{
grok {
   match => { "my_field" => "%{GREEDYDATA}/%{WORD:filename}.%{WORD}:%{GREEDYDATA}/%{WORD:filename2}.%{WORD}:%{GREEDYDATA}/%{WORD:filename3}.%{WORD}" }
 }
}
```

You could be more strict in grok with use of PATH in place of GREYDATA, I let you determine your best approach that works in your context.

You could debug the grok pattern with the online tool [grokdebug](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: how can I remove the suffix from file1 ?

Comment: You mean remove the first part of the path (in your case /var/) ?

Comment: I mean if the first file is /var/log/mylog.log I want to get only the "mylog" string

Comment: And how do u handle a case with more than 3 files ?

Comment: For more thant 3 files, just add another pattern in the grok (:%{GREEDYDATA:file4} for example), this works only if the number of field is static, that why I've ask this in comment. If not, it's not possible with only grok.

Comment: worth adding this comment in the answer. How would u handle the suffix problem ?

Comment: For extract the filename (basename) without extension this pattern works : %{PATH}/%{WORD:filename}.%{WORD}:%{PATH}/%{WORD:filename2}.%{WORD}

Comment: thanks ! :) Is it best practice to use the grok filter, or it doesnt really matters if I use grok or ruby code

Comment: If you have the choice between grok or ruby, I advise you to use grok for more reason : 1) less code more pleasure ;) 2) Less code less maintenance 3) performance leak is less possible with grok than ruby 4) is more easly readable ( this point could depends..)

Comment: Got Timeout execution grok when using the PATH keyword. Instead, replace it with GREEDYDATA. Can you please update your answer ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225472/discussion-between-ylr-and-jeyj).